# Extra foreign key in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, foreign-key-relationship, entity-framework-6, fluent-interface

I designed employee and employee relation tables as shown below:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public EmployeeType EmployeeType { get; set; }

    public int? ReportingManagerId { get; set; }

    public Employee ReportingManager { get; set; }

    public virtual List<EmployeeRelation> Colleagues { get; set; } 
}

public class EmployeeRelation
{
    public int EmployeeRelationId { get; set; }

    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public Employee Employee { get; set; }

    public int ColleagueId { get; set; }

    public Employee Colleague { get; set; }
}
```

And corresponding configuration classes as:

```
   public class EmployeeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Employee>
    {
        public EmployeeConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(e => e.EmployeeId);
            Property(e => e.EmployeeId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
            HasOptional(e => e.ReportingManager).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.ReportingManagerId);
        }
    }
public class EmployeeRelationConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<EmployeeRelation>
{
    public EmployeeRelationConfiguration()
    {
        HasRequired(e => e.Employee).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.EmployeeId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        HasRequired(e => e.Colleague).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.ColleagueId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

With the above code, everything is fine except that, for the table EmployeeRelations, EF 6.0.2 is creating one additional ForeignKey for EmployeeRelation as Employee_EmployeeId (in addition to EmployeeId & ColleagueId ForeignKeys). But if, I use Data Annotations instead of Fluent API, this extra ForeignKey is gone. I don't like Annotations and want to use Fluent API only. Can someone help me what is wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
I resolved it myself.
Problem is multiple relations. If we look at EmployeeRelation class, it has 2 properties of type Employee which are binding to the Employee class and this is where EF is getting confused. To avoid this problem, we need to use overloaded version of WithMany API:

```
HasRequired(e => e.Employee).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.EmployeeId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
HasRequired(e => e.Colleague).WithMany(e => e.Colleagues).HasForeignKey(e => e.EmployeeId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: What happens when you remove EmployeeConfiguration's ReportingManager config stuff and add Property(e => e.ReportingManagerId).IsOptional();

Comment: It has nothing to do with ReportingManagerId property. I researched it and found the solution; please see my update. Thanks for your reply.